# Creating an intent in Google dialog flow V2 API using postman

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create intent in an agent I created in google dialog flow. I'm able to create intent through the Google API console. But when I'm trying the same through Postman, I'm getting authentication error. I'm not sure what exactly is the authrization type I should be using and which key I should me made use of for this. What is the authorization type used to create intent in V2 and which is the key used for this and where can I get these keys?

I'm providing the details of what I tried below. What's that I'm missing or made mistake in ?

URL: https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{project name}/agent/intents?languageCode=en

Authorization: oauth2 and client id I used as key

Request body:

```
{
  "displayName": "ListRooms",
  "priority": 500000,
  "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
  "trainingPhrases": [
    {
      "type": "EXAMPLE",
      "parts": [
        {
          "text": "What rooms are available at 10am today?"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": "listRooms",
  "messages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Here are the available rooms:"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below  request

- use api url
- post method to send request in header
- add authentication as Bearer,
  your developer access token and content `type = application/json`.

```
    {
      "contexts": [
        "shop"
      ],
      "events": [],
      "fallbackIntent": false,
      "name": "add-to-list3",
      "priority": 500000,
      "responses": [
        {
          "action": "add.list",
          "affectedContexts": [
            {
              "lifespan": 5,
              "name": "shop",
              "parameters": {}
            },
            {
              "lifespan": 5,
              "name": "chosen-fruit 1",
              "parameters": {}
            }
          ],
          "defaultResponsePlatforms": {
            "google": true
          },
          "messages": [
            {
              "platform": "google",
              "textToSpeech": "Okay. How many $fruit 1?",
              "type": "simple_response"
            },
            {
              "speech": "Okay how many $fruit?",
              "type": 0
            }
          ],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "dataType": "@fruit",
              "isList": true,
              "name": "fruit",
              "prompts": [
                "I didn't get that. What fruit did you want 1?"
              ],
              "required": true,
              "value": "$fruit"
            }
          ],
          "resetContexts": false
        }
      ],
      "templates": [
        "@fruit:fruit ",
        "Add @fruit:fruit ",
        "I need @fruit:fruit "
      ],
      "userSays": [
        {
          "count": 0,
          "data": [
            {
              "alias": "fruit",
              "meta": "@fruit",
              "text": "oranges",
              "userDefined": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "count": 0,
          "data": [
            {
              "text": "Add "
            },
            {
              "alias": "fruit",
              "meta": "@fruit",
              "text": "bananas",
              "userDefined": true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "count": 0,
          "data": [
            {
              "text": "I need "
            },
            {
              "alias": "fruit",
              "meta": "@fruit",
              "text": "apples",
              "userDefined": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "webhookForSlotFilling": false,
      "webhookUsed": false
    }
```

Hope this help